# Как поменять класс объекта на его сабкласс сохраняя все атрибуты и инстанции?

Tags: python, ооп

Подскажите как без использования каких-либо библиотек и внешних методов и функций поменять класс объекта сохраняя все его бывшие инстанции.

Код снизу это представление иерархии компании, класс работников (Worker), класс начальников (Boss) и класс корпорации(Corporation). У Boss и Worker все атрибуты кроме одного идентичные. Как поменять работника на начальника (и наоборот) сохраняя все эти атрибуты и место в иерархии. Подскажите как именно инцициализировать смену класса в методе promote_or_demote(), так чтобы все сохранилось и внутри иерархии произошли изменения?

```
class Worker:
    """ self.subworkers это список прямых подчиненных работников. """
    id: int
    position: str
    grade: int
    subworkers: List[Worker]
    
    def __init__(self, id: int, workplace: str, age: int, position: str, grade: int) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.workplace = workplace
        self.age = age
        self.position = position
        self.grade = grade
        self.subworkers = []

class Boss(Worker):
     """ Класс наследует все инстанции Worker."""
     _company: str

     def __init__(self, id: int, workplace: str, age: int, position: str, grade: int, 
                                                                        company: str) -> None:
        Worker.__init__(self, id, workplace, age, position, grade)
        self._company = company

class Corporation:
      """Класс корпорации"""
      _leader: Optional[Worker]

     def __init__(self, leader: Optional[Worker] = None) -> None:
          self._leader = leader

     def promote_or_demote(self, id: int, company_name: Optional[str] = None) -> Worker:
         """ Поменяйте тип рабочего с этим <id>.
         Повысьте Worker до Boss или понизьте Boss до Worker. Все инстанции должны сохранится.
         Верните нового работника/босса.
         Условие: Если <id> это id Boss'а, то company_name должно быть None """
```

Comment: В питоне нельзя взять и поменять класс существующего экземпляра. Вообще, из условия задачи не ясно, где хранятся все рабочие, т.е. откуда взять рабочего по id в методе `promote_or_demote`. Так как напрямую класс поменять нельзя, то правильное решение от этого сильно все зависит. Возможно имеется ввиду, что его нужно искать среди рабочих начиная с `_leader`? Но что делать если `_leader` пустой?

Comment: Извиняюсь за путаницу, забыл уточнить, что мне важно просто сохранить атрибуты при изменения класса(если это возможно).  Рабочие сохраняются в  атрибуте subworkers.
Где его нужно искать и тд тоже в контексте вопрос не имеет значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, id_: int, workplace: str, age: int, position: str, grade: int) -> None:
        self.id_ = id_
        self.workplace = workplace
        self.age = age
        self.position = position
        self.grade = grade
        self.subworkers = []

    def promote(self, comp):
        return Boss(self.id_, self.workplace, self.age, self.position, self.grade, comp)


class Boss(Worker):
    def __init__(self, id_: int, workplace: str, age: int, position: str, grade: int, company: str):
        super().__init__(id_, workplace, age, position, grade)
        self._company = company

    def demote(self):
        return Worker(self.id_, self.workplace, self.age, self.position, self.grade)

anyone = ... # Boss or Worker
anyone = anyone.demote() if isinstance(anyone , Boss) else anyone .promote(company_name)
```

Я вас натолкну на мысль, а вы уже её внедрите как вам нужно, так сложно понять что вы хотите.

Советы:

1. id - зарезервированое слово в Python, используйте другое имя для атрибута
2. Почитайте о super(), для вызова родительских функций используйте его.
3. Не вызывайте магические методы напрямую(Worker.**init**), для них есть реализация правильная
4. Все атрибуты для будущих обьектов обьявляются только внутри **init**, вне **init** вы обьявляете атрибуты класса, почитайте об этом, также посмотрите на встроену либу dataclasses
5. Если метод или функция ничего не возвращает можете не писать для неё тайпинг.

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, можно ли так делать в плане правил кода, но чисто механически класс можно сменить путем замены атрибута `__class__`. При такой смене метод `__init__` класса, на который вы сменили вызываться не будет

```
class A:
    def print(self):
        print(self.__class__)

    def change_class(self):
        self.__class__ = B

class B(A):
    pass

obj = A()
obj.print()
obj.change_class()
obj.print()
```

Вывод:

```
<class '__main__.A'>

<class '__main__.B'>
```

Comment: Такой же вопрос на другом форуме: https://question-it.com/questions/91882/izmenenie-klassa-obekta-python-privedenie